# Chef-client does not work from Workstation but does work directly on the server

Tags: sql-server-2012, chef-infra

I have a chef recipe that runs a chocolatey install for Microsoft SQL server. From my workbench when I run

```
knife winrm [IP] 'chef-client -o "recipe[NetDevMachine::default]"' -m -x 'domain\myuser'
```

over a node it fails with the error:
532459699 or sometimes 2022834173 or 2057043966

However if I log onto the VM as the same user and locally run

```
chef-client -o "recipe[NetDevMachine::default]"
```

It works. Does anyone know what the difference is between running chef-client locally and running it remotely from the workbench? What does chef-client do differently here? Both are pulling the recipe from the same chef-server repo.

Additional Details

- I am using the same user for both
- I have successfully run other recipes from the workstation, it's just this MicrosoftSQLServer install that's not working
- running "knife winrm [IP] 'choco install MicrosoftSQLServer' -m -x 'domain\myuser' also does not work

Recipe contents:

```
powershell_script "choco install MicrosoftSQLServer2014" do
    code <<-EOH
    choco install MicrosoftSQLServer2014
  EOH
end
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Running C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\MicrosoftSQLServer2014\setup.exe with 
/QUIET /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=INSTALL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /FEATURES=SQL,TOOLS,LOCALDB 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS 
/SKIPRULES=REBOOTREQUIREDCHECK UIMODE=AUTOADVANCE  was not successful. 
Exit code was '-532459699'.
```

Edit - the only difference I can see is that one runs in the foreground and the other doesn't. So the location of the compile chef-script is /temp/2 for the failing run. I don't know if there is a way to force chef to run in the foreground or if that will even help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this and still don't understand how running the chef client remotely using knife was different from running chef client directly on the VM. Perhaps it was something to do with the handling of credentials or permissions when remotely sending commands.

But I did find that removing chocolatey and replacing it a command line silent install inside a chef powershell resource allowed me to install MSSQL.